# Stack Overflow app for iOS and Android

Tags: discussion, android, ios

I'm not sure if it's proper to ask this question on Stack Overflow itself, but I'm really eager to find a good Stack Overflow app for my iPhone and Android phone, so I can login to my Stack Overflow and ask/answer questions. I tried a few but none is perfect, some can't support iOS 7 perfectly, others don't support login. Can anyone help?

Comment: Only in android version. Still in alpha

Comment: given no official iOS version, any other iSO apps recommended?

Comment: An official iOS application is in the works as well, still not ready for alpha.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS I often use - [SOStacked](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sostacked/id427708024?mt=8), A paid app. Has an ability to login with your SO account and you can perform almost all the actions from the mobile app. Simple to use and has a good interface.

I don't use android much, but yes you can give it a try by downloading [SOClient](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sudosaints.stackoverflow&hl=en), free app from android play store. It has a functionality to login with your SO Account.